# How can I convert this equation

Tags: polynomials

How can I convert this equation:
$$321^2 - 196^2 = 64625$$
to be in this form:
$$X^2 - Y^2 + X = 64625$$

Whereas $X$ and $Y$ are Odds and $X > \sqrt{64625}$

I tried to find $X$ value by testing the values from 255 until 321 and I found $X=257$ and $Y=41$. So I would like to asking the mathematicians if there is any mathematical solution to find $X$ and $Y$ values?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Convert this equation" - what is that supposed to mean? The first equation has no relevance.

Comment: Yes, it's equal but I just need to change the equation to be in the form $X^2 - Y^2 + X$ and I would like to know if there is any mathematical solution to do that ? Thanks

Comment: @PeterForeman Is't impossible ? or my question was wrong ?

Comment: I'm quite sure the solution you gave is the only one, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks alot for your reply. I will try to read and search and I hope some one guide me or correct my understanding.

Comment: There's a solution where $X=Y= 64625.$ You can't actually use the first equality to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Times the equation by $4$, add 1 & complete the square
\begin{eqnarray*}
4X^2+4X+1-4Y^2=4 \times 64625+1
\end{eqnarray*}
which gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2X+1)^2-(2Y)^2=\color{red}{(2X-2Y+1)}\color{blue}{(2X+2Y+1)}=258501=\color{red}{433} \times \color{blue}{597}.
\end{eqnarray*}
etc ...

Comment: You can also use the factorization $$\color{red}{1}\cdot 258501.$$ That gives $X=Y= 64625.$

Comment: ... or $1299\times199$ to get $(X,Y)=(374,-275)$, or $597\times433$ to get $(X,Y)=(257,-41)$ or $258501\times1$ to get $(X,Y)=(64625,-64625)$.

Comment: nice prove but this is in case X==Y. but what if X !=Y ?. I was thinking the differnce between two squares in the first equation will guide me to prove that. thanks for correction